# didUpdateLocations will call on stable phone or now?

Tags: iphone, ios, cllocationmanager

I want to know that `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` will call when my phone is in stable position?

In my case its not calling when i put my phone on one place.

I Placed my phone from one location to other location within my room but still its not calling.

Can anyone tell me that when it will call.

When i change location using `xcode` then its always calling.

I used

```
self.locMgr.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you say within the simulator it works, but it does not work when you run your program on the actual iPhone device, right?

You were correct in setting the accuracy. This should work actually unless you have switched off the location update in general for your iPhone (settings under Privacy->Location Services).

If this is all working you maybe want to paste more of your code, but again, I think if it works under the simulator it should work on the device.

Comment: i run it through device, then location manager call once , and then i change location from xcode then it will call regular.

Comment: If you do not get GPS it might be that your location is only determined because of your WiFi or Cell Tower. So maybe you need to go outside to really get the effect or "take a walk".

Answer (score 1):

The location manager calls for location updates on the accuracy you set. It will not get called on a stable location more than once. you can use distance filter to call it after a certain distance.

```
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10; //meters
```

For updating it on the same location you will have to use a timer which will call for updating after every desired interval.

Comment: i will try this.. but to update on server, we will call after an interval  like 15 minut, but what if we have same location?

Comment: store the location in user defaults. and put a check for it. If its the same location then don't update. If its a new location the update and store that location in defaults

Answer (score 0):

```
Probably it depends on the accuracy you set to the locationManager.
```

> 1).. Cell Radio 2).. WiFi Map, 3).. GPS
>
> If you set best as accuracy the location manager will continue to
>   check you position, if the location with better accuracy is out of the
>   range of the distance filter the delegate method will be called again.
>
> GPS is not exact.some time if you move about a feet and still it will
>   not update. or some time you didn't moved at all and it will update.

Answer (score 0):

**Stop testing GPS and `Location Services` inside! Go outside and move around to test it.**

Answer (score -1):

> Make sure that you set the delegate for the Location Manager & also
>   make sure you get the permission for using "User's Current Location."

Comment: here problem is not that delegete is not called... problem is that why its not called even he moves a phone

Comment: @BhavikKama, see hol's answer.

Comment: he said at last "I think if it works under the simulator it should work on the device." so there must not be any type delegete set problem .. till now...from the statement @Rajneesh071 said its working on simulator